# Excel, how to subtract time to span before midnight

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to subtract hours to a time that is close to midnight, but excel is outputting all hash (#) symbols complaining of the operation.

Adding time is easy and possible, as described by this first example:

For example, I have a cell with the value 11:00 PM (the column is formatted to this time format). I need to add 2 hours to it and get 01:00 AM. Assuming that cell A1 has the `11:00 PM` value, I use `=A1+time(2,0,0)` and get 01:00 AM, which is what I expect.

However, when I try the reverse of this operation (minusing), excel outputs all hash symbols.

For example, I have a cell with the value 01:00 AM. I need to minus 2 hours to it and get 11:00 PM. I try `=A1-time(2,0,0)`, but all I get are hash symbols from excel.

How can I subtract a number of hours (or minutes) from a time that is very close to midnight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of

`=A1-TIME(2,0,0)`

is a negative value if A1 = 01:00, and excel doesn't like negative time values in most cases, hence #####.

Try using `MOD` function like this

`=MOD(A1-TIME(2,0,0),1)`

Answer (score 2):

The formula, that you need is actually:

`=MOD(B1-A1,1)` where `B1` is the past midnight time and `A1` is the before midnight one.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I use what I was told is a 36 hour clock.  If the shift begins prior to midnight but ends after midnight use a modified 24 hour clock.  For example:

Shift begins at 11:00 PM and ends at 5:00 am; format the cells using the 24 hour clock = Format Cell - Time - 13:30

Formula is: 
 29:00
-23:00 results should be 6 hours.

If you're doing hours and minutes you may have to custom format the Total(s) cell to 
The end times are easy to figure out: Midnight is always 24:00, add an hour for each hour following midnight (i.e. 1:00 am = 25:00, 2:00 am = 26:00 and so on...).

Comment: I guess that you’re describing how to compute times that span midnight ***by hand*** — but I’m not even sure of that; I can’t really make much sense of it.  But I don’t see ***anything*** that even begins to discuss how to do this in Excel.