# Substracting times over midnight in excel, maintaining the correct date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd be happy to get some help to an issue in Excel.
I need to subtract hours or minutes from a given time. All works fine until the calculation goes before 24:00. 
Example: 3:00 - 5 hrs = -2
Be correct answer would be 22:00.

It is important that the solution is Excel-based (no VBA or add-ins) and that the date changes respectively. As I already have 20x3 Columns, I would very much like to avoid extra columns...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you doing =A1-TIME(5,0,0) where A1 has the start date/time? In A1 I put =now(), and then in A2 I put =A1-TIME(5,0,0) which results in A2 showing now - 5hrs

Comment: Hi, thanks for a quick response. However, I have a fixed time in A1, not the actual time...

Comment: Sure, but the same logic applies assuming the cells are formatted correctly

Comment: 03:00 less 5 hours is 22:00 not 23:00 - is this what you mean?

Comment: That's what I meant. 

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error subtracting times](https://superuser.com/questions/990913/error-subtracting-times)

Answer (score 0):

If you store 5 hours in Excel it will be stored as 5am on 00/01/1900 in Excel (thanks to @Forward Ed for this correction).

Assuming that the date/time you want to subtract from is after the year 1900 you can simply format cells as time or date and subtract.

As mentioned in comments below dates/times are stored as numbers starting from 00/01/1900 and as you can see in picture below subtracting the numbers and converting back to dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss gives the same result.

[image: Times with numbers]

Comment: Minor correction.  Date and Time in excel are stored as a number.  The integer portion represents the number of days since 1900/01/00.  Meaning 1900/01/01 is 1.  The portion after the decimal represents time.  Better yet fraction of a day.   0.5 is noon. 24:00 does not exist, but 00:00 does.  You don't need to add 24 days  in your equation, you only need to add 1.  The reason you don't see the issue is the cell format is only displaying the time portion and not the date as well.

Comment: @Forward Ed -I have updated picture so all fields are  "dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss".  Adding 24 still seems to work.

Comment: With the date added to A being in the future compared to B, your condition check in your IF statement will always be false.  So you are simply doing A-B which should work since you have the date part added and you wont wind up with a positive number.  Set the date for A = B and test again

Comment: @Forward Ed - you are correct.  I will try to update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your support!

I finally found the solution here:

1. [Excel, how to subtract time to span before midnight](https://superuser.com/questions/735491/excel-how-to-subtract-time-to-span-before-midnight#)
2. https://www.exceltip.com/excel-date-time-formulas/avoiding-errors-when-subtracting-times.html
   you just need to know what to search for!

basically instead of adding 24 hrs they suggest to use the MOD function and it works!

Comment: Using MOD however does not respect the date correctly (it strips the date from a date/time field and sets it to 01/01/1900).  Preserving the date was a requirement as your question said "It is important that … the date changes respectively."

Comment: I beg your pardon - if you format the result calculated using MOD as date (rather than time which gives correct results) it is 00/01/1900 not 01/01/1900 in Excel 2016.   Quite why Excel thinks the zero of January is a date is another question...

Comment: Yes, I ran into that problem now. The search continues 